# Do I need to upload the entire BS4 library to use it on a webserver?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Not really sure where to ask this, so I'm trying out Stackoverflow... I want to use BS4 as part of a python script on a website. How do I import the BS4 library to use it? Would I have to upload the entire library on the web server to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install it on your server

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
# or
python -m pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

if you can't execute that command, try download latest file from offcial page [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/), extract it and upload `bs4` directory same with your script directory.

Answer (score 0):

Same as you'd use it in any other script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Your options on how you are getting your `html_doc` are opened up...
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/